# Why Do Mobile Phones refuse to read Math.max values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, math, mobile-devices

So long story short, I have been working on a Full Stack website for a client and I have it all finished however I have an issue!

For some reason when I use `Math.max(...shipArray)`, It will work correctly on PC but when you try to view it on mobile. It returns NaN, this also effects the `shoppingTotal`!

Anyways here's my code:

```
    const shippingCost = () => {
    const basket = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("productData"));
    const shipArray = [];
    let shippingTotal = 0;
    if(!basket)
    setBasketEmpty(true);

    basket.map((item, key) => {
        shipArray.push(item.product.shipping_cost);
    });

    console.log(shipArray)

    shippingTotal = shippingTotal + Math.max(...shipArray);
    updateShoppingTotal(shippingTotal);
}


    const updateShoppingTotal = (shipping) => {
    var tempCost = 0;
    var finalCost = 0;
    var tempCostArray = [];
    var quantity = window.localStorage.getItem("productData");
    if(!storageData)
    setBasketEmpty(false);

    if(quantity){
        JSON.parse(quantity).map(quan => {
            tempCost = quan.product.product_price * quan.quantity;
            tempCostArray.push(tempCost);
    });

    tempCostArray.forEach(item => {
        if(!isNaN(item)){
            finalCost = finalCost + item + shipping;
        }
    });

    setShipping(shipping);
    window.localStorage.setItem("originalPrice", parseFloat(finalCost).toFixed(2));
    window.localStorage.setItem("basketTotal", parseFloat(finalCost).toFixed(2))
    setShoppingTotal(parseFloat(finalCost).toFixed(2))
}
}
```

I'm also using ReactJS, not React-Native.

Thanks

EDIT: Just to be on the safe side, I tried to put some random numbers in manually and it does appear to be the `shipArray` that's the issue, so If anyone knows why it could be adding a non-number to the array then that would be helpful!

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have yes, at first I thought there may have beene and undefined value but that wasn't the case

Comment: Narrow this down to a specific test case.

Comment: could always use reduce `const maxShippingCost = basket.reduce((max, item) => item.product.shipping_cost > max ? item.product.shipping_cost : max, basket[0].product.shipping_cost);`

Comment: @Carcigenicate the type is an integer, one thing it might be the the Math function may be running before i push the data into the array.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, ill give it a go soon!

Comment: maybe you local storage data gets corrupted?

Comment: @Itamar Nah I think I've narrowed it down to a non number value in the array which I think is because the array starts off empty and doesn't update properly on mobile so I'm going to try something different tomorrow. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had a brain I'd be dangerous! LOL

So to view a product I had 2 Components, one for larger devices and one for mobiles.

For the the first Component, I added the shipping cost to localStorage but I didn't do that for the mobile Component so when i tried to read the `item.product.shipping_cost` on mobile, it of course couldn't find it so was saying `undefined`.

THIS BLOODY LINE HERE:
`oldBasket.push({product: {shipping_cost:this.state.productData.shipping_cost,});`

That line wasn't on the Mobile Component!

Thanks for the advice though everyone

Answer (score 1):

It could be the spread operation `...`

If you're testing on old phones (and especially things like those cheap "burner" TracFones) then they don't have a lot of modern JS features (pretty sure no spread, no arrow functions, maybe even no let?).

I used to develop for those and a lot of modern JS stuff you can't use. They are often running Android 4.4 or earlier.

A nice resource is [can I use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_spread_spread_in_function_calls) (link to spreads). You'll notice that isn't supported in Android 4.4

**edit:** if this code is being transpiled by Babel it probably replaces this kind of thing with something more old school.

Comment: I don't think it's the phone I'm using as it's a Galaxy S10+. However it could be Babel like you said! I did try to explicitly set the number array in the Math.max function instead of the `shipArray` and and It worked as intended. So I can only assume the function will run twice on PC when the data in the array changes but on Mobile it doesn't and will only read the empty `shipArray`